# My Stage is not responding in my while loop

Tags: java, javafx

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    public static void menu(Stage stage){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String option;
        GridPane layout = new GridPane();
        do {
            System.out.println("1.Enter Y to show the Window\n2.Enter N to continue\n3.Enter Q to Quit");
            System.out.print("Enter Option : ");
            option = input.next();
            if(option.equals("Y")) {
                stage.show();
            }

        }while (!option.equals("Q"));
    }
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Window");
        menu(stage);
    }
```

My window that opens says in the title not responding.This is kinda like the logic of the problem I have in the program I've made for my coursework

Comment: What exactly is your problem? And what do you want to achieve? As far as I understand you want to open the stage and the query should continue to run. Is that correct?

Comment: If you want to continue to loop through options after the user chooses to show the window, you will need to move the loop and the console input to a separate thread; so you'll need to read a tutorial on multithreaded programming in Java and JavaFX. That is an advanced topic and I absolutely do not recommend it for beginning programmers.

Comment: So this program that I am supposed to make is a train booking system where I have my menu in console and it has some options like adding seats and viewing booked or empty seats & other options that are used in console. 

These options should be viewed in a GUI. I should be able to loop the menu for the user to select these options untill they enter "Q".

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are not ending the loop, add a loop break after showing the stage :

```
if(option.equals("Y")) {
  stage.show();
  break;
}
```

Comment: But I want to continue the loop and ask the user input again.

Comment: @LuqmanRumaiz When you call `menu()`, the `start` method will wait for it's response or until `menu()` is finished, but if you show the stage and stay looping, the `start` method will never get a callback and this will cause a timed out error.  
Another thing, if you notice after showing the stage, the window title is not 'Window' as set with `stage.setTitle()`, which means `start` is not completing as I said.

Comment: Oh, I see damn do you know of a way to fix this then. Also for me when I run the program the stage title appears.

Comment: @LuqmanRumaiz There should be a way but only if you give more clarity about what you are trying to achieve, in your example, the case of N is never used, and Q will not "really" quit and stop the process.

Comment: yo check the latest comment for the question I said it.

Comment: @LuqmanRumaiz You have two solutions for that: either you implement a "console simulator" in your view. For example a simple `TextField` where the user input something, you do some logic and then clear the field for another action.  
**Or**, use threads to split your program into two separated tasks, but as @James_D said, that's an advanced topic, [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)  is the documentation for it, but before reading I really suggest you to learn some theory on what are threads and what are the advantages of using them.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: Oh wow makes sense I could do something that makes the user to input something never thought of that. Yeah, I don't think I'd understand threads now. Thanks a lot bro :)!!!!!!!!!!!